# OpenMP and smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, openmp, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to parallelize what is equivalent to following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> intPtr;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  intPtr foo = intPtr(new int(-1));

  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

    *foo = i;

    cout << *foo << " ";

  }

}
```

For reasons that are beyond my control, and that cannot be appreciated in the example, I need to stick to the shared pointer. This is my current attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> intPtr;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  intPtr foo = intPtr(new int(-1));

  bool firstOfThread = true;
  int fooPriv = *foo;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) firstprivate(firstOfThread,fooPriv,foo)
  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

    if(firstOfThread){
      foo.reset(&fooPriv);
    }

    *foo = i;

#pragma omp critical
    cout << *foo  << " ";


    firstOfThread=false;
  }

}
```

This compiles and prints the 0-9 series, but it is giving me `glibc detected` errors. In the past, I've worked with bare pointers successfully using the same strategy, with `foo=&fooPriv;` instead `foo.reset(&fooPriv);`, but there is something I'm missing here. I suspect it has something to be with the extra pointer inside `foo` that counts the number of calls, so I'm not correctly making a "deep-copy", as it is mentioned in other question/forums, but I haven't been able to solve it. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The output of the program is sometimes this:

```
*** glibc detected *** omp-test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff5da6a7bc ***
0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 Aborted (core dumped)
```

And sometimes this:

```
*** glibc detected *** omp-test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffc210277c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3853875e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x385387897a]
omp-test[0x401bc9]
omp-test(main+0xab)[0x401ccb]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x385381ed5d]
omp-test[0x4018e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 9568302                            /data/disk01/home/imc/sandbox/scripts/aerie-apps/liff-HealpixSigFluxMapGen/omp-test
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:15 9568302                            /data/disk01/home/imc/sandbox/scripts/aerie-apps/liff-HealpixSigFluxMapGen/omp-test
01339000-017f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3853000000-3853020000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359298                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
385321f000-3853220000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 2359298                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3853220000-3853221000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 2359298                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3853221000-3853222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3853400000-3853402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359303                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3853402000-3853602000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 2359303                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3853602000-3853603000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2359303                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3853603000-3853604000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2359303                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3853800000-385398a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359302                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
385398a000-3853b8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 2359302                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3853b8a000-3853b8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 2359302                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3853b8e000-3853b8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 2359302                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3853b8f000-3853b94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3853c00000-3853c17000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359314                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3853c17000-3853e17000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 2359314                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3853e17000-3853e18000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 2359314                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3853e18000-3853e19000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 2359314                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3853e19000-3853e1d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3854000000-3854083000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359316                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3854083000-3854282000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 2359316                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3854282000-3854283000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 2359316                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3854283000-3854284000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 2359316                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3854400000-3854407000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359320                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3854407000-3854606000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 2359320                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3854606000-3854607000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 2359320                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3854607000-3854608000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 2359320                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3854800000-3854815000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359336                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3854815000-3854a14000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 2359336                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3854a14000-3854a15000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 2359336                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3854a15000-3854a16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2359336                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3855400000-3855415000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1725449                        /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
3855415000-3855614000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 1725449                        /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
3855614000-3855615000 rw-p 00014000 fd:00 1725449                        /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
3855c00000-3855c16000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2359508                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3855c16000-3855e16000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2359508                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3855e16000-3855e17000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 2359508                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3855e17000-3855e18000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 2359508                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3855e18000-3855e1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3857800000-3857816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2373979                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3857816000-3857a15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2373979                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3857a15000-3857a16000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 2373979                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3857a16000-3857a17000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 2373979                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3857a17000-3857a19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3857c00000-3857c02000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2373980                        /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3857c02000-3857e01000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 2373980                        /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3857e01000-3857e02000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 2373980                        /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
3857e02000-3857e03000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 2373980                        /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
385b800000-385b898000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1711172                        /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.22
385b898000-385ba97000 ---p 00098000 fd:00 1711172                        /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.22
385ba97000-385ba9d000 rw-p 00097000 fd:00 1711172                        /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.22
385f400000-385f410000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2361304                        /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
385f410000-385f60f000 ---p 00010000 fd:00 2361304                        /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
385f60f000-385f611000 rw-p 0000f000 fd:00 2361304                        /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4
38b0800000-38b0816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2366780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
38b0816000-38b0a15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2366780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
38b0a15000-38b0a16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2366780                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
38b0c00000-38b0ce8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1732781                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
38b0ce8000-38b0ee8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 1732781                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
38b0ee8000-38b0eef000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 1732781                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
38b0eef000-38b0ef1000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 1732781                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
38b0ef1000-38b0f06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffbb8000000-7ffbb8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: what was the error(s)? That can provide more context.

Comment: @AJG85 I edit the post with the output, that include the errors. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`reset()` is intended to replace the shared object reference not modify the object itself. Internally shared_ptr uses an atomic for reference counting which will increment on assignments, copies, etc and decrement as destructors are called and things go out of scope until finally destroying the managed object and releasing memory. Reset or swap is used to replace the underlying object managed with another instance.

`*foo = obj;` should make a deep copy provided the assignment operator is overloaded to do so for the managed object in question. In your example a copy of the int value.

`foo = maked_shared<int>(fooPriv);` may be what you want for the initial copy perhaps? In that case you would want to ensure firstOfThread is false after the initialization and then merely share the reference across the other threads so they can update the value. Preferably within a critical section to avoid tearing and race conditions.

This is just general guidance as without knowing what errors you encountered or having a specific question it's hard to pinpoint exactly what you're looking for.

**Edit:** Update based on error log. It looks like it tried to free an invalid pointer. This can be caused by a double delete or lost reference. With a shared pointer you could initialize it before the parallel section and rely on the reference counting as it's passed to each thread stack to keep it in scope. Then protect any reads and writes within the thread function to avoid race conditions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> intPtr;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  intPtr foo = intPtr(new int(-1));

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) firstprivate(foo)
  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
#pragma omp critical
    *foo = i;
    cout << *foo  << " ";
  }
  // join or wait for threads to complete here, if needed with OpenMP
} // foo gets deleted
```

P.S. We have shared_ptr in standard c++11 and newer if your compiler and tool chain supports it as well. It's based off the boost implementation and works the same way.

Comment: Thank for you answer @AJG85 . Yes, with the reset I'm trying to only replace the object reference, from `*foo=-1` to the private copy op `fooPriv`, which is copied for every thread since it's inside `firstprivate`. Each thread needs its own copy of `*foo` since it gets modified. And yes, I'm setting `firstOfThread=false` at the end, since each thread needs a copy, not each iteration.

If `foo` were a bare pointer, it works perfectly by changing `foo.reset(&fooPriv)` to `foo=&fooPriv`

Comment: The checking of the flag and reset was not protected though so it would be possible for one or more threads to think they are first before the flag is set false and cache is updated for other threads to see the new value. If you want each to have it's own copy perhaps sharing a pointer is not needed at all? I was thinking it was shared because the order of operations being performed did not matter so long as each took place at some point. i.e. the value of foo would be set to the final iteration of the last thread to exit which could change from one run to the next.

Comment: I tried your code above, but it outputs thing like `0 0 7 1 8 2 9 3 10 4 5`. This happens because one thread can set the value of `foo` in the time between the assignment and printing statement of the other thread. This can be resolved, in this simple example, but enclosing both, the assignment and  printing statement in a single block under critical, but that would defeat the purpose of the parallelization.

And yes, the order doesn't matter.